# Find 3D coordinate on same plane as given 3 coordinates

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry, physics

I have 4 coordinates on a plane and coordinates $A,B,C$ are known. Line $AB$ is 90 degrees to line $AD$. The distance between $A$ to $D$ is 3 meters. I am trying to find coordinate $D$.

The coordinates are:
$A=(2,-4,7),\\  
B=(3,-5,4)  ,\\ 
C=(0,0,0)$

[Plot of 4 coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVe3z.png)

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried using 2D trigonometry sense they are on the same plane. But that would not give me the 3D coordinate.

Comment: What properties of a plane do you know so far? Do you know that 3 points can uniquely define a plane? Can you find the normal vector to this plane?

Comment: Yes, I know 3 points make a plane. I would have to Google how to find the norm it has been too long sense I had to do it in school. I am messing around with some 3D paths for a game.(looking at the norm now)

Comment: Once you found the normal of the plane, you can find the direction of $AD$, taking the cross product of $AB$ with the normal (since the 3 lines are mutually orthogonal). This gives 2 solutions for $D$.

Comment: Found the normal vector = 19i + 13j + 2k. (now working on finding the direction of AD)

Comment: Another way to approach this is that $D$ is the intersection of a sphere of radius $3$ and two planes.

Comment: Thanks amd. This is good to know.

Comment: @David how did you get 3/(sqrt(5874))?

Comment: We want to scale the vector so that it is of length 3, thus we first divide the vector by it's magnitude ($\sqrt{37^2+(-59)^2+32^2}=\sqrt{5874})$ (by Pythagoras Theorem) to make it unit and multiply by the required length 3.

Comment: @David Thanks for your you time in figuring this out and helping me along the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the normal to the plane by taking the cross product $\vec{CA}\times\vec{CB}=  \begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
           2 \\
           -4 \\
           7
         \end{pmatrix}
\times \begin{pmatrix}
           3 \\
           -5 \\
           4
         \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
           19 \\
           13 \\
           2
         \end{pmatrix}
  \end{align} = \colon \vec{n} 
$.

Since we are in 3-dimensions, and we know $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AD}$ are both perpendicular to the normal and to each other, we can find the direction of 
$\vec{AD}$ by $ \vec{AB} \times \vec{n}= \begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
           1 \\
           -1 \\
           -3
         \end{pmatrix}
\times \begin{pmatrix}
           19 \\
           13 \\
           2
         \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
           37 \\
           -59 \\
           32
         \end{pmatrix}
  \end{align}
$.

Hence, $\vec{OD}= \begin{pmatrix}
           2 \\
           -4 \\
           7
         \end{pmatrix}\pm\frac{3}{\sqrt{5874}}\begin{pmatrix}
           37 \\
           -59 \\
           32
         \end{pmatrix}$.